# Get lat/long given current point, distance and bearing

Tags: geodesy, geodesic

While searching the web, I've encountered the following formulas for calculating the destination point P2's location given the source point P1 = (lat1,long1), the distance from it & the bearing:

```
lat2 = math.asin( math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) +
   math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng))

lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),
   math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))
```

Where P2=(lat2,lon2).

I was trying to develop the math behind it but could not really get it right

Can someone please show me how to develop the lat2 & lon2 mathematically?

Comment: So you want to know the theory behind the equations? Perhaps see Rapp's Geometric Geodesy [Part I](https://kb.osu.edu/handle/1811/24333) and [Part II](https://kb.osu.edu/handle/1811/24409). If that's what you are looking for, let me know so I can turn this into an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much mkennedy, for the links, but Gabriel De Luca's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

*What follows is a development of the formulas found in the [Aviation Formulary by Ed Williams](http://www.edwilliams.org/avform147.htm#LL) and in [Movable Type Scripts by Chris Veness](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), from the formulas of spherical trigonometry, to solve the direct problem of geodesy (obtain the coordinates of the destination point, knowing the azimuth of origin and the distance traveled over a great circle) on a spherical surface:*

This is not a map of the Earth.  This is a map of a spheric world, whose `Radius = 1` (dimensionless).

[image: map]

In this map, a spheric triangle was drawn.
The vertices of the triangle are:

`N` North pole.
`1` Start point of a travel.
`2` End point of a travel.

The travel was started with initial azimuth `alpha_1`, and traveled a distance `s`.

The distance, on the unit sphere, is equivalent to the angle covered by the arc traveled, in radians.
If you want to perform your calculations over a sphere of radius `R`, and travel a distance `d`, you need to transform:
`s = d / R`.

`lambda`are longitudes, in radians.
`phi` are latitudes, in radians.

One side of the triangle measures `s`, and the other two measure the respective collatitudes of the vertices (`PI() / 2 - phi`).

`lambda_1`, `phi_1`, `alpha_1` and `s` are given.

---

- First, calculate `phi_2`.

From the [Spherical Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), we know that:

`COS(PI()/2-phi_2 ) = COS(PI()/2-phi_1) * COS(s) + SIN(PI()/2-phi_1) * SIN(s) * COS(alpha_1)`

But, whether we remember the trigonometric identity for the cosine of a subtraction, or remember that the sine is the same function as the cosine, out of phase `PI()/2`:

`COS(PI()/2-phi_2) = SIN(phi_2)` and `COS(PI()/2-phi_1) = SIN(phi_1)`

Therefore:

**`SIN(phi_2) = SIN(phi_1) * COS(s) + COS(phi_1) * SIN(s) * COS(alpha_1)`**

---

- Then, calculate `lambda_2`

The angle at `N` is `lambda_2 - lambda_1`, `delta_lambda` from now.

Write the cosine law for the `s` side of the triangle.

`COS(s) = COS(PI()/2-phi_1) * COS(PI()/2-phi_2) + SIN(PI()/2-phi_1) * SIN(PI()/2-phi_2) * COS(delta_lambda)`

Or better:

`COS(s) = SIN(phi_1) * SIN(phi_2) + COS(phi_1) * COS(phi_2) * COS(delta_lambda)`

Therefore:

`COS(delta_lambda) = (COS(s) - SIN(phi_1) * SIN(phi_2)) / (COS(phi_1) * COS(phi2))`

Now, write the [Spherical Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines#Spherical_case) that describes the relationship between `delta_lambda` and `s`, in terms of the relation between `alpha _1` and `PI()/2-phi_2`:

`SIN(delta_lambda) / SIN(s) = SIN(alpha_1) / SIN(PI()/2-phi_2)`

Therefore:

`SIN(delta_lambda) = SIN(alpha) * SIN(s) / COS(phi_2)`

Now, the tangent of `delta_lambda`:

`TAN(delta_lambda) = SIN(delta_lambda) / COS(delta_lambda)`

Simplifying *on-the-fly*:

`TAN(delta_lambda) = SIN(alpha_1) * SIN(s) * COS(phi_1) / (COS(s) - SIN(phi_1) * SIN(phi_2))`

Finally, write `lambda_2` in terms of `delta_lambda` and `lambda_1`:

`lambda_2 = lambda_1 + delta_lambda`

Therefore:

**`lambda_2 = lambda_1 + ATAN(SIN(alpha_1) * SIN(s) * COS(phi_1) / (COS(s) - SIN(phi_1) * SIN(phi_2)))`**

Note the ambiguity that the arctangent function returns the same result for opposing arguments, so it must be decided whether to add (or subtract) `PI()` to its result, based on the quadrant in which the argument is. This ambiguity is solved by the [ATAN2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much Gabriel De Luca for the very elaborated explanation. there is one tiny mistake to fix in your explanation: The last term in the phi_2 calculation should be: SIN(phi_2) = SIN(phi_1) * COS(s) + COS(phi_1) * SIN(s) * COS(alpha_1). again thanks a lot.

Comment: Edited. You are welcome!