# Derivation of Lat/lon given radial and distance

Tags: latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry

I'm looking for a derivation of the following aviation formula. I found this on one or two other sites as well but no explanation.

http://www.edwilliams.org/avform147.htm#LL

I took a stab at this myself. The destination latitude comes directly from the cosine rule for sides applied to the colatitude using two great circles through the North Pole and a third great circle through the origination and destination.

I tried using the same technique to get the angle at the North Pole, opposite the line of longitude. What I came up with was the following.

cos(dlon) = (cos(d/R) - cos(colat1)*cos(colat2)) / (sin(colat1)*sin(colat2))

Colat1 and colat2 are the origination and destination colatitudes, respectively. D/R is the angular length. If I plug in small random numbers, I get the same result as in the link above. But I can't see how to get to either of the two formulas starting from what I have here.

Comment: Hi Todd, welcome. Can you check if this answer helps you?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313006/133276

Comment: I spent hours looking for this! It's a shame your answer doesn't show up more readily in a google search.

Comment: I included a preliminary note in the answer using some terms so that it will be taken into account in future searches.